# Get the response in Silverpop IBM SaveMailing API

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js

I am using JS Engage sdk to call saveEmail API. I am getting an error in API response call back but not able to get the response.

```
  ibmIMCIntegration.oAuthClientId = value["IBMIMC"].oAuthClientId;
                            ibmIMCIntegration.oAuthClientSecret = value["IBMIMC"].oAuthClientSecret;
                            ibmIMCIntegration.oAuthRefreshToken = value["IBMIMC"].oAuthRefreshToken;
                            // var arrOfClickThroughs = [{clickThroughName:"ingagechatbutton",clickThroughType:2,clickThroughURL:$scope.messangerID}];
                            var parameters = {
                                header:{
                                    mailingName:$scope.mailingName,
                                    subject: $scope.subject,
                                    listId: 85326,
                                    fromName: $scope.fromName,
                                    fromAddress: $scope.fromAddress,
                                    replyTo: $scope.replyTo,
                                    visibility: 1,
                                    encoding: 6,
                                    trackingLevel: 2,
                                    clickHereMessage: false
                                },
                                messageBodies:{
                                    htmlBody:newSource
                                },
                                // clickThroughs:{
                                //     clickThrough:arrOfClickThroughs
                                // },
                                forwardToFriend:{
                                    forwardType:0
                                }
                            };

                            ibmIMCIntegration.parameters = JSON.stringify(parameters);
             var userJson = {
                type:"saveMailing",
                options:ibmIMCIntegration,
            };
            console.info("List IBM Template  | User JSON:" + 

            JSON.stringify(userJson));
            var url = 'api/db/invokeIBMIMCOperation.php';
            $http.post(url, userJson)
                .success(function(res) {
                    if (res) {
                        if(res.isSuccess === true) {
                            swal("", "Your template has been created successfully", "success");
                            document.getElementById("form1").reset();
                        }
                        else {
                            swal("", "Please try again", "error");
                        }
                        console.info(res);
                    }else{
                        swal("", "Please try again", "error");
                    }
                });
```

Here is my API funciton call:

```
function saveMailing(engage,parameters,ctx){
engage.saveMailing(parameters,function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Failed to load Save aMailing: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

}

where I am now getting result array. If I am sending wrong parameter then it print the error console but if I got success to save template then it just print "{}".

Is there anyway I can get the response. ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for getting response from the Engage node.js sdk.

The reason behind getting the null response is Sdk tries to delete the response. I don't know why they are deleting the response. sdk only sends error message response in call back.

For getting the **success** response :

Open the file **engage-xml-api.js** from engage-api/lib folder.

find `delete(response.Envelope.Body.RESULT.SUCCESS);` line and comment it.

You will get the successful response if your query is correct.

Thanks